# Show long if condition in BI Publisher RTF template with short text

Tags: bi-publisher

Below empty grey color field has if condition in the advance properties. I have added an If condition to the rtf template. I want to display it with short text or empty text like below.

[Field with empty text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZTys.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty5HQ.png)

I have the if condition as below.
[If condition] [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xg74.png)

I tried to see the properties. But nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the entire if condition in the "advanced" tab of that properties.

[Example](https://you.stonybrook.edu/pnotes/2016/03/18/if-then-else-statements-in-bi-publisher/).

Comment: I have this if condition <?if:Customer_Name='Apple'?> Show below region end if. It doesn't show any option to see advanced properties.